# How can I add values to a field on discord embed message?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am trying to vertically add values to a field with a for loop.

I tried this piece of code:

```
for a in variants:
    embed.add_embed_field(name="Sizes", value=a.text, inline=False)
```

variants is an array of html div elements and im trying to display the texts inside them but this way, it re-adds the title because of the for loop outside of it. how can i use the for loop to add multiple values in that field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming I've understood correctly; you need to turn `variants` into a str and pass that as the value.

One way of doing that is using `join`:

```py
var_str = ", ".join([v.text for v in variants])
embed.add_field(name="Sizes", value=var_str, inline=False)
```

This makes your list of items a single value and we pass it in accordingly.

Note: embed field values can only be `1024` characters long, so you might have to add some handling for that if that's going to be an issue.